# Crashlytics could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, crash-reports, crashlytics

i found the problem regarding Crashlytics. i've successfully integrated the crashlytics in eclipse. and configured my sample android app with api key in `AndroidManifest.xml` file with `meta-data` tag. and `Crashlytics.start(this)` in my activity class. but when i try to run it, it gives me error that 
**Crashlytics could not be initialized, API key missing from AndroidManifest.xml.** when the entry is already there in menifest file. following is the error log.

[image: error_image]

please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Marc from Crashlytics here. Below is a sample AndroidManifest.xml - that should help you out. Also, we're happy to help through support at crashlytics dot com.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="com.example.myapp"
              android:versionCode="1"
              android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <application android:label="@string/app_name">
                <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                          android:label="@string/app_name">
            </activity>

            <meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" 
                       android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks. that solved the problem. but that's weird, crashlytics tool is automatically adding meta-data tag inside __activity__ tag while configuring the project for crashlytics. so i've moved the <meta-data> tag from activity to application tag. and one more thing ,while configuring the crashlytics it does malformed the structure of manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Could you e-mail support@ with the details so that we can dig deeper into it?

Comment: Hi Kunal, i also want to integerate crashalitics in android but i am not able to find libraries/jars for this ,could you help to get it or any link for the same.Please reply ASAP.

Comment: Is putting the API key in the Manifest absolutely necessary?  What if I am a developer on a project, and I don't know the API key?

Answer (score 2):

Can you post what you have written in `AndroidManifest.xml`? (Except your API key of course).

A couple questions to help determine the issue:

1. Have you placed the `<meta-data>`-tag inside the `<application>`-tag?
2. Have you kept the `com.crashlytics.ApiKey` as the `android:name`?
3. Also, do you use libraries which makes you have multiple `AndroidManifest.xml` files?

Comment: 1.yes i've placed it in <application> tag.
2.Yes.
3.No. i m not using any library.

Comment: I'm having an issue which I think is caused by point 3; My app depends on a library with a manifest and manifest merging enabled.
Does this cause issues with crashlytics?

Comment: I have the same problem. My PhoneGap app has Google Play Services library linked. And after CrashLytics installation I got this error: Unknown error merging manifest

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16941925/2128921) mentioned above.

My issue was that Gradle was using an older, pre-Fabric library. When I attempted to use the new Fabric plug-in, it generated the following:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="myapikey1234" />
```

Notice that the name refers to Fabric. Changing this to the following resolved this issue:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
        android:value="myapikey1234" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated Crashlytics from an old version, with meta data `android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"` changing to `android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"`. This broke my release build since DexGuard removed the metadata element that it thought was unused.

Fix is to add *dexguard-project.txt* with one line:

```
-keep class io.fabric.** { *; }
```

At the time of writing this, [Crashlytics documentation on DexGuard](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html#exclude-crashlytics-with-proguard) is not up-to-date yet.